# FluentValidation Set Valid Result to a Custom Property

Tags: .net-5, fluentvalidation

I am validating the content for file import and I have an `IsValid` property for each line.

```
public class Header 
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

public class Trailer
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

public class ImportFile
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    public Trailer Trailer { get; set; }
}
```

and my validators look somewhat like:

```
public class DetailValidator : AbstractValidator<Detail>
{
    public DetailValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Property1)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithState(d => d.LineNumber)
            .Length(3)
            .WithState(d => d.LineNumber);

        RuleFor(d => d.Property2)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithState(d => d.LineNumber)
            .MaximumLength(50)
            .WithState(d => d.LineNumber);

        ...
    }
}

public class ImportFileValidator : AbstractValidator<ImportFile>
{
    public ImportFileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(f => f.Header)
            .SetValidator(new HeaderValidator());

        RuleForEach(f => f.Details)
            .SetValidator(new DetailsValidator());

        ...
    }   
}
```

After I call the validation, I wanted to set the `IsValid` property of each line of the file (be it header, detail or trailer) base from the result of the validation.

What is possible for now is, since I am using `WithState` to store the `LineNumber`, I can match the `ValidationResult` against the `ImportFile` instance to set each line's validity like below:

```
ImportFile file = // parsed file content
var result = new ImportFileValidator().Validate(file);

foreach (var detail in file.Details)
{
    var error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault(e => 
        Convert.ToInt32(e.CustomState) == detail.LineNumber);

    detail.IsValid = error == null;
}
```

And I have to check for the header and trailer as well.

Is there a way I can do this inside the validators? I am trying to explore the FluentValidation's documentation, but I can't seem to find what I needed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was exploring the available methods in FluentValidation, I saw `OnFailure` and `OnAnyFailure` methods. This methods might be a good help to what I needed to do, but the problem is they're obsolete as of `10.3.0` and will be removed on version `11`. They're suggesting to use a custom validator instead.

1. The Header, Detail and Trailer Abstract Validators remain as is.
2. I created custom validator extensions for those 3.

Each extension methods creates an instance of the corresponding validator and executes it. I can make them generic for header, detail and trailer since they will do the same thing, set IsValid property to the validation result.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions<ImportFile, T> IsHeaderValid<T>(this IRuleBuilder<ImportFile, T> ruleBuilder)
    where T : Header
{
    return builder.Custom((header, context) =>
    {
        // Create the Header Abstract Validator Instance
        var validator = new HeaderValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(Header);

        header.IsValid = result.IsValid;

        // Pass the errors to the context
        result.Errors.ForEach(context.AddFailure);
    }
}
```

3. I had to change the ImportFileValidator to call the custom validators, instead of using setvalidator.

The ImportFileValidator looks like this:

```
public class ImportFileValidator : AbstractValidator<ImportFile>
{
    public ImportFileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(f => f.Header)
            .IsHeaderValid();

        RuleForEach(f => f.Details)
            .IsDetailValid();

        ...
    }   
}
```

This is pretty much how I was able to set the `IsValid` property without having to do the matching I initially did in the question.